# Menu bar Error in xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

does anyone know how to fix this error?

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

Conflicting return type in implementation of 'supportedinterfaceOrientationMask'(aka 'enum UIInterfaceOrientationMask') vs 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the documentation changed in iOS 9, if you go to UIViewController.h it now declares supportedInterfaceOrientations as:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```

if you change the return type Xcode will stop complaining.

Comment: Thank you that fixed it.